# Extract words between the 2nd and the 3rd comma

Tags: python, regex

I am total newbie to regex, so this question might seem trivial to many of you.
I would like to extract the words between the second and the third comma, like in the sentence:

```
Chateau d'Arsac, Bordeaux blanc, Cuvee Celine, 2012
```

I have tried : `(?<=,\s)[^,]+(?=,)` but this doesn't return what I want...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data = "Chateau d'Arsac, Bordeaux blanc, Cuvee Celine, 2012"
import re
print re.match(".*?,.*?,\s*(.*?),.*", data).group(1)
```

**Output**

```
Cuvee Celine
```

But for this simple task, you can simply split the strings based on `,` like this

```
data.split(",")[2].strip()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I just add `\s` after the second comma because I didn't want the comma being part of the output. Thanks once again !

Answer (score 5):

In this case I see easier to use a simple split by comma.

```
>>> s = "Chateau d'Arsac, Bordeaux blanc, Cuvee Celine, 2012"
>>> s.split(',')[2]
' Cuvee Celine'
```

Comment: For a problem where you can use `str.split()` (or any other method on `str` for that matter), that's generally going to be way faster than using a regular expression...

Comment: @Matt Anderson ; I didn't know it impacted on execution time ; is the impact important ?

Comment: Is the impact important? Depends on the circumstances; the scale. If you you're running on a dataset in the gigabytes, it can make a big impact.  If you're working on inputs that are less than a megabyte, you probably can't notice the difference. Big data does appear in real world problems though, so, definitely sometimes...

Answer (score 3):

Why not just split the string by commas using [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) ?

```
 data.split(",")[2]
```